# Using strategy_regexp for the TestRunner action?

Tags: bazel

The *TestRunner* action is excluded from strategies set using the command line
parameter *strategy_regexp*. What are the reasons for not being able to map strategies
for the *TestRunner*?
In the code there is a comment on not overriding test strategies for
backwards compatibility. Do you know what test strategies it may conflict with?

Code that excludes the *TestRunner*:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/exec/SpawnStrategyRegistry.java#L93

The background is that I would like to map individual C++ unit tests to remote execution but cannot find any support for that in Bazel? Is there perhaps some other mechanism that can be used for this?

Kind regards,

Jonas Hansson